# Somehow DateTime.now() milliseconds gets extra decimal points after sending to, and getting response from remote database- Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, parse-platform

I'm saving a "Book" object to a Hive database, it looks like so:

```
title: Creation of Dreams
author: Kosmas Brink
publishingDate: 1998-11-02 00:00:00.000
dateAdded: 2021-06-22 19:39:48.847
lastModified: 2021-06-22 19:39:48.847
```

dateAdded & lastModified are both DateTime.now()

***PROBLEM***

Json Serializable is altering my DateTime.now() somehow. This is causing errors when I try to compare objects in local db to remote db, of course the same objects are not exactly the same because of this and I get an error. It looks like this on remote db and when returned from the remote db:

```
{
    "title": "Creation of Dreams",
    "author": "Kosmas Brink",
    "publishingDate": "1998-11-02 00:00:00.000",
    "dateAdded": "2021-06-22 19:39:48.847716",
    "lastModified": "2021-06-22 19:39:48.847717"
  }
```

My json serializer file is turning DateTime toString(). Instead of toIso8601String(). So I have no idea why this is occurring.

Question:

- So, why am I getting extra accuracy for milliseconds randomly?
- More importantly, is there a better way, like using millisecondsFromEpoch or something?

EDIT: Adding serializer

```
// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Book _$BookFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Book(
    title: json['title'] as String,
    author: json['author'] as String,
    publishingDate: DateTime.parse(json['publishingDate'] as String),
    dateAdded: DateTime.parse(json['dateAdded'] as String),
    lastModified: DateTime.parse(json['lastModified'] as String),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$BookToJson(Book instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'title': instance.title,
      'author': instance.author,
      'publishingDate': instance.publishingDate.toString(),
      'dateAdded': instance.dateAdded.toString(),
      'lastModified': instance.lastModified.toString(),
    };
```

Comment: `48.847716` and `48.847717` are a microsecond appart. Like the time it takes to store from one field to the other. It looks like the second display is more accurate than the first one, which may only consider milliseconds? (disclaimer: I don't know the tools you use)

Comment: Can you share the serialization part?

Comment: Added serialization. @Breakingnotsobad i don't know what that has to do with my question. My object saving saves `.847` and the json object is saving `.847717`...

Comment: @JigarPatel the original code gen was .toIso8601String() but I changed it to .toString(). This originally solved the exact problem I'm having now. But then I restarted all my databases to retest my project and now I have the exact same issue once again using .toString().